# Vue/Nuxt 3 Getting type error when using only named v-models

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue, Nuxt 3 Typescript project.

In my custom component I am binding two values with *named v-models*. It **works** but in the parent component I see a type error.

The error goes away when I use `modelValue` in the custom component alongside named ones but I don't want that, I only want named v-models.

1. Custom Component

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  min: number;
  max: number;
}>();

defineEmits(["update:min", "update:max"]);
</script>

<template>
  <UFormGroup label="Min">
    <UInput
      :value="props.min"
      @input="$emit('update:min', $event.target.value)"
      type="number"
      placeholder="Min"
    />
  </UFormGroup>
  <UFormGroup label="Max">
    <UInput
      :value="props.max"
      @input="$emit('update:max', $event.target.value)"
      type="number"
      placeholder="Max"
    />
  </UFormGroup>
</template>
```

2. Parent Component with Type Error

```js
<ChangeTypesRandomValue
       v-model:min="item.min"
       v-model:max="item.max"
/>
```

Error Screenshot:
[image: Error while using named v-models]

```
Argument of type '{ min: any; max: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<{}> & Omit<{ readonly modelValue: any; "onUpdate:modelValue"?: ((value: any) => any) | undefined; } & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & Readonly<...> & { ...; }, never> & Record<...>'.
  Property 'modelValue' is missing in type '{ min: any; max: any; }' but required in type 'Omit<{ readonly modelValue: any; "onUpdate:modelValue"?: ((value: any) => any) | undefined; } & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & Readonly<...> & { ...; }, never>'
```

It appears that modelValue is required? It shouldn't be. [Vue Docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#multiple-v-model-bindings) say that just named v-models are fine. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
I understand from the comments that this is a TypeScript issue with my environment. However, I am using the default configuration with Nuxt:

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  // https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
}
```

Without tampering with anything else, I assume the types should allow omitting the default v-model `modelValue` props & emit and keep only the named bindings.

Comment: It's specific to the place where you see the error (IDE), the question doesn't make sense when asked in general

Comment: It's a typescript error, which is specific to your environment and typescript configuration.  it is not an issue with Vue, and in fact your code will work just fine at runtime.

Comment: I've made an edit for tsconfig. I understand my code will work. My environment uses the default Nuxt 3 tsconfig so ideally it should support Vue's named v-models without requiring the default one with `modelValue`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 'props' in a template

Use
:value="min"
:value="max"

instead of
:value="props.min"
:value="props.max"

```js
<template>
  <UFormGroup label="Min">
    <UInput
      :value="min"
      @input="$emit('update:min', $event.target.value)"
      type="number"
      placeholder="Min"
    />
  </UFormGroup>
  <UFormGroup label="Max">
    <UInput
      :value="max"
      @input="$emit('update:max', $event.target.value)"
      type="number"
      placeholder="Max"
    />
  </UFormGroup>
</template>
```

Comment: That is the preferred way to use props in template because they will automatically be unwrapped, but if you _do_ use the `props` object, Vue will still handle it just fine. Your answer is more of a recommendation than a necessity.  More importantly, it does not resolve the issue in question.